# Facebook login using Javascript SDK - user authentication

Tags: facebook, security, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token

Using Javascript SDK, I am trying to use Facebook Login to allow users to access my spring based (2.5.6) application. Once the access token is retrieved, I can then make FB call to retrieve basic profile information using the token. If I successfully receive basic profile information from FB, is it sufficient to allow user access to my application? Is there any other authentication process required at the server?

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you care about is user login, I would say you're good to go. If you need to get additional information, check [this document](https://developers.intern.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5)